# How to show sequence table in sequence folder

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sequence, soa, bpel

I'm working on a SOA BPEL process where it's reading data from an XML file and load it into database tables. However, the table sequence I need to call in my transformation file is not showing in the sequence table, but it can be queried (see below query). Because of this, it returns an error where transformation file is failing as it treats these sequences non-existent. I need to call these sequences for me to be able to generate sequencing values for the table IDs.

```sql
SELECT XXTG_SAMPLE_HEADER_S.nextval FROM DUAL;
SELECT XXTG_SAMPLE_LINES_S.nextval FROM DUAL;
```

Here are the only sequence showing in the folder:
[image]

Here I'm calling them in my transformation file:

```xml
<tns:repairId>
    <xsl:value-of select="oraext:sequence-next-val ('XXTG_SAMPLE_HEADER_S', 'jdbc/timexappsDataSource')"/>
</tns:repairId>

<tns:repairLineId>
    <xsl:value-of select="oraext:sequence-next-val ('XXTG_SAMPLE_LINES_S', 'jdbc/timexappsDataSource')"/>
</tns:repairLineId>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only *simple* explanations for the error `ORA-02289: sequence does not exist` when you can ad Hoc *query* it.

Let's list them

- the sequence *exists*, but in a different database than your process is connected to.
- the sequence *exists*, but in a different schema than your process is using to connect.

Solution of the former case is obvious.

In the latter case

- check the schema of the sequence

`select SEQUENCE_OWNER from all_sequences where sequence_name = 'XXTG_SAMPLE_HEADER_S';`

- check the user your process connects
- grant SELECT on the sequence to the connect user

connect with the user that created the sequence and

`grant select on seq_user.XXTG_SAMPLE_HEADER_S to connect_user;`

Comment: Already grant permission but still the transformation file doesn't see these sequences. Is there a way that those sequences will show in the sequence table? Unfortunately, only those 3 sequences on the screenshot are seen by the transformation file.

Comment: Forget *transformation file*  you must realize which `user` connects to the database. Check the configuration and search for *user+, *password*. This `user`must get the grant.